# Como transformar, por exemplo, "0" em "ZERO" em C? Qual problema nesse código?

Tags: c, string

Tenho que fazer um programa pra faculdade cujo objetivo principal é outro, mas em uma das etapas do programa, preciso passar dois números randômicos inteiros de 0 a 9 para seus formatos extenso escrito, em *string*. Escrevi alguns trechos de um código que desempenharia isso, mas não tive muito sucesso.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int i=0, rand1, rand2;
    char num1[7], num2[7];

    printf("Bem vindo! Pronto pra começar? Vamos la!");

    srand(time(NULL));

    while (i<10){
          rand1=rand()%10;
          rand2=rand()%10;

           switch (rand1){
            case 0:
                 num1 = "ZERO";
            case 1:
                 num1 = "UM";
            case 2:
                 num1 = "DOIS";
            case 3:
                 num1 = "TRES";
            case 4:
                 num1 = "QUATRO"
            case 5:
                 num1 = "CINCO";
            case 6:
                 num1 = "SEIS";
            case 7:
                 num1 = "SETE";
            case 8:
                 num1 = "OITO";
            case 9:
                 num1 = "NOVE";
            }
          switch (rand2){
            case 0:
                 num2 = "ZERO";
            case 1:
                 num2 = "UM";
            case 2:
                 num2 = "DOIS";
            case 3:
                 num2 = "TRES";
            case 4:
                 num2 = "QUATRO"
            case 5:
                 num2 = "CINCO";
            case 6:
                 num2 = "SEIS";
            case 7:
                 num2 = "SETE";
            case 8:
                 num2 = "OITO";
            case 9:
                 num2 = "NOVE";
            }


          printf("Quanto e %s vezes %s?: ", num1, num2);

          i++;
          }
    system("pause");
    return 0;


}
```

O erro se dá na atribuição da string `num1` e `num2` com a mensagem

> incompatible types in assignement of 'const char [5]' to '[char [7]'

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Você pode começar escrevendo as palavras do seu texto por extenso. Não é necessário abreviar, tem bastante espaço para escrever as palavras por inteiro. Se quer economizar digitação, é só não colocar palavras que não acrescentam nada ao entendimento do que está sendo escrito. Use as *tags* corretas para chamar a atenção das pessoas certas. Consertei o problema de formatação do seu código. Utilize o ícone `{}` no editor para colocar código.

Comment: Além do que já foi informado pelos colegas em respostas, o seu código tem outro probleminha no [comando `switch`](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/c/switch-case-default.php). Como você *não usou* o `break` em cada caso, todos vão ser executados em sequência e a sua variável vai ficar com o valor da *última* execução *independentemente do valor de `rand1`* (`num1 = "NOVE"`, por exemplo). Então, não esqueça do `break`, ok? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você declarou `char num1[7]`. É uma array com 7 caracteres. Mas no C não existe operação de atribuição de arrays. Então `num1 = "ZERO"` não funciona.

1. Pode transformar `num1` e um ponteiro para char apenas, assim quando fizer `num1 = "ZERO"` ele vai apontar para a array de chars estática. Recomendo assim já que você não pretente alterar os dados de forma alguma.
2. Usa a função `strcpy` para copiar a string para a array: `strcpy(num1, "ZERO");`. Funciona para o que você quer, mas a cópia é desnecessária já que você não vai mudar os dados. Um mero ponteiro basta.

---

Não relacionado, mas uma forma melhor de escrever o seu código seria a seguinte:

```
const char* words[10] = {"ZERO", "UM", "DOIS", "TRES", "QUATRO", "CINCO",
                         "SEIS", "SETE", "OITO", "NOVE"};

char* num1 = words[rand1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Não é poss'ivel atribuir valores a arrays. Precisas de atribuir aos elementos do array um a um. A linguagem C tem uns atalhos para facilitar essa atribuição quando se trata de *strings*.

```
num1[0] = 'Z';
num1[1] = 'E';
num1[2] = 'R';
num1[3] = 'O';
num1[4] = '\0';
```

ou, usando o atalho

```
strcpy(num1, "ZERO"); // lembra-te de incluir o header <string.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na linguagem C você não pode atribuir uma cadeia de caracteres para um vetor simplesmente utilizando o operador de atribuição '='. Isso serial possível se estivesse utilizando o tipo string do C++.

Entretanto, existe um conjunto de funções no C incluídas no arquivo de cabeçalho  dentre as quais posso citar strcpy que copia uma cadeia de caracteres para um vetor de char. Então na sua comparação, caso seja número 6, faria:

```
char str[256];
strcpy(str, "SEIS");
```

E você teria agora a cadeia de caracteres salva no seu vetor. Ele copia a cadeia da direita para dentro do seu vetor à esquerda desde que tenha tamanho suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre o erro de compilação já tem boas respostas: não pode atribuir valores assim em C. `int` e `char[7]` com um texto representando o tal `int` são coisas bem distintas e não há uma conversão direta.

E o `case` está errado: faltam os `break`;

Tempos depois, vou sugerir o potencialmente muito mais rápido e muito mais simples

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* numero[] =
    {
        "ZERO", "UM", "DOIS", "TRES", "QUATRO",
        "CINCO", "SEIS", "SETE", "OITO", "NOVE"
    };
    char num1[7] = {0};
    char num2[7] = {0};
    printf("Bem vindo! Pronto pra começar? Vamos la!\n");
    srand(210821);
    int total = 10;
    for(int i=1;i<=total;i+=1)
    {
        int rand1 = rand() % 100;
        strcpy(num1, numero[rand1 / 10]);
        strcpy(num2, numero[rand1 % 10]);
        printf("[%2d/%2d]  %s   e   %s\n", i, total, num1, num2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Que mostra

```
Bem vindo! Pronto pra comeþar? Vamos la!
[ 1/10]  SEIS   e   TRES
[ 2/10]  SEIS   e   SEIS
[ 3/10]  UM   e   OITO
[ 4/10]  QUATRO   e   SEIS
[ 5/10]  ZERO   e   ZERO
[ 6/10]  TRES   e   DOIS
[ 7/10]  SEIS   e   SEIS
[ 8/10]  UM   e   ZERO
[ 9/10]  UM   e   OITO
[10/10]  SEIS   e   QUATRO
```

Sem nenhum switch e com uma só chamada a `rand()`.