# Erro em retorno de ponteiro na função

Tags: c, ponteiro

Galera, estou com o seguinte erro:

incompatible types when assigning to type 'char [30] ' from type 'char *'

o código é o seguinte:

```
    int main()
{
    char *resultado[30];
    float valor = 12735.98;
    resultado=monet(valor);  \\O AVISO DE ERRO É AQUI
    printf("%s \n",resultado);

}

char *monet(float v){
    static char *str[30];
    sprintf(str,"R$ %2f",v);
    return &str;
}
```

Comment: Posso te ajudar, preciso entender um pouco melhor seu raciocínio, me de algumas informações sobre o que você pretende fazer.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui imprimir aqui:

```
char *monet(float v){
    static char str[30];
    sprintf(str,"R$ %.2f",v);
    return str;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *resultado;
    float valor = 12735.98;
    resultado=monet(valor); 
    printf("%s \n",resultado);

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *resultado[30];
static char *str[30];
```

`resultado` e `str` são arrays de 30 apontadores! Nenhum dos 30 apontadores de nenhum dos arrays aponta para um sítio válido!

Quando usas apontadores deves saber sempre para onde eles apontam.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a essa altura vc já deve ter entendido o problema. De qualquer forma, aqui vai minha resposta: acho que, de acordo com o que foi mostrado na resposta anterior, o seu erro foi retornar `&str` ao invés de `str`. O primeiro retorna provavelmente um inteiro, já que se refere a um endereço de memória. Já o segundo retorna o ponteiro `str` que você criou na função. Espero ter ajudado!